# How to read some file data and write it to another file?

Tags: python, file, byte

So, i'm trying to read a file data ( bytes ) and write it to another file. like this

it's important to know that i need the bytes. copy and paste doesn't work for me, because i want to use this in a tcp server

i just want to know how i can read some data file and then paste it in another file. so later i can implement it in a socket script.

```
#PYTHON
file=open('someicon.ico','rb')
data=file.read(1024) #reading data
file2=open('someicon2.ico','wb')
file2.write(data) #writing data in another file
file,file2.close()
```

but it's not working. can anyone help me? it's a simple thing but idk how to fix it. thx :D

Comment: I would suggest to look at `shutil` module

Comment: i'll do it right now. thx for reply

Comment: i forgot to say. i want to use this in a server by sockets, so i can't ( just copy and paste) i need the bytes..

Comment: Your example is about files. Can you edit your question and specify more your problem?

Comment: yeah sure, i'm so sorry about this. i'm newbie here

Comment: if you want to use it in tcp server then show code where do you use tcp server. Code for server may need different functions then normal file - you may need `socket`, `send()`, `recv()` and client may need to read normal file, send() data, and server may have to recv() data and write it as normal file

Comment: i just want to understand how it works, then i can put it in a tcp server because i know how to do this, my problem here is understand how i can read some file data and then paste it in another file. thank u for replying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This copies `file.txt` to `file2.txt` 1 byte at time (you can increase this constant, or leave it to -1 (default, read all data at once) ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read)):

```
with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_in, \
    open('file2.txt', 'wb') as f_out:

    while True:
        data = f_in.read(1) # this reads one byte
        f_out.write(data)

        if not data:
            break
```

Comment: hey, can i do the same but with pictures ( png ) instead of text files (txt) ?

Comment: @VictorLucasMazzotti Of course, with any file. It doesn't matter of extension.

Answer (score 0):

`file,file2.close()` doesn't seem right to me.

can you explicitly call `close()` on each of the file handlers?

ps: someone can convert this to a comment(can't post comments yet)

Comment: i tried to do this, but nothing happens.. it still doesnt work. thx for replying